# On click Listener called twice

Tags: android, android-widget

I know this is easy but i m just not able to debug it.

I am dynamically creating 3 LinearLayouts and adding them to a scroll View . I am adding a Button "ins" to the top of 3 linearlayout.

The problem is that on clicking the ins Button , its on clicklistener is being called 3 times . 
code:

```
package com.integrated.mpr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Page1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    static int pos = new Choose().n;
    static String partname;

    int i;
    int[][] id = new int[pos][5];


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int p =0;
        for(int i =0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j =0;j<5;j++){

                p++;
            }
        }


        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        int resid = getResources().getIdentifier("background", "drawable", getPackageName());
        ll.setBackgroundResource(resid);

        Button ins = new Button(this);
        ins.setText("Instructions");
        ins.setOnClickListener(this);
        ins.setId(5000);

        ll.addView(ins);

        for(i =0;i<3;i++){


            LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this);
            llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("enter the " +(i+1)+" position name");


            EditText et = new EditText(this);
            et.setId(id[i][0]);

            Button starta = new Button(this);
            starta.setText("Record 1");
            starta.setId(id[i][1]);
            starta.setOnClickListener(this);

            Button startb = new Button(this);
            startb.setText("Record 2");
            startb.setId(id[i][2]);
            startb.setOnClickListener(this);


            Button startc = new Button(this);
            startc.setText("Record 3");
            startc.setId(id[i][3]);
            startc.setOnClickListener(this);


            Button stop = new Button(this);
            stop.setText("Submit");
            stop.setId(id[i][4]);
            stop.setOnClickListener(this);

            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setVisibility(llay.INVISIBLE);

            llay.addView(tv);
            llay.addView(et);
            llay.addView(starta);
            llay.addView(startb);
            llay.addView(startc);
            llay.addView(stop);
            llay.addView(tv1);
            ll.addView(llay);

        }
        Button bcon = new Button(this);
        bcon.setText("Continue");
        bcon.setId(10000);
        bcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll.addView(bcon);


        sv.addView(ll);

        this.setContentView(sv);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(v.getId()==5000){    
            Log.d("ins", "called");
            Context mContext = Page1.this;
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            dialog.setTitle("Instructions");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.instructiondialog);
            dialog.show();


            }

        }
    }






}
```

I know definitely , there is some problem in the code of OnCreate but what it is ? Help please

Can anyone further explain how to set the button aligned o the right of screen , that is how to set its layout gravity?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with declaring it inside the for loop...

Comment: Exactly , but can u be a bit more exact

Comment: As GAMA says, if you loop three times, and define an onclick listener in each loop, you'll get three onclicklisteners, which will all be invoked when the user presses the button.

Comment: i have not defined the onclick listener of ins Button in a loop , its outside the loop

Comment: @kumarpiyush i think nothing is wrong with your code as i have copy paste ur code it called instruction click on single not a three times

Comment: Thanks for ur effort i rectified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about what exactly you want to achieve.but you can set the flag.if flag value is 1 then only process onClick else not.

Below snippet will help you.

Yes but you will have to somehow reset that flag to 1.

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
           {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(v.getId()==5000)
                {    
                if(flag)
                 {
                   Log.d("ins", "called");
                   Context mContext = Page1.this;
                   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
                   dialog.setTitle("Instructions");
                   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.instructiondialog);
                   dialog.show();
                 }
                flag=0;
                }
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also call button click event like this

```
Button ins = new Button(this);
ins.setText("Instructions");
ins.setOnClickListener(this);
ins.setId(5000);

ins.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Context mContext = Page1.this;
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setTitle("Instructions");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.instructiondialog);
        dialog.show();
    }
});
```